# extract data from nested JSON key/values

Tags: json, bash

Suppose I have a JSON file which contains something like this:

```
{
  "inx": {
    "tthd": {
      "status": 200
    }
  },
  "tech": [
    {
      "slug": "microsoft-l",
      "name": "Microsoft l"
    },
    {
      "slug": "windows-s",
      "name": "Windows S"
    }    
  ]
}

{
  "inx": {
    "sssdg": {
      "status": 200
    }
  },
  "tech": [
    {
      "slug": "linux-l",
      "name": "linux l"
    },
    {
      "slug": "ubu-s",
      "name": "ubu S"
    }    
  ]
}
```

This file contains the output of a command which extracts "tech" section for each "inx" and writes the result inside this .json file.

Using bash, I want to check if there is a `"slug": "microsoft-l"`, and in case it exists, return its `"inx"` value.

For example, in above JSON, I want to find `"slug": "microsoft-l"` and then return its `"inx"` value, which is `"tthd"`. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you use `jq`?

Comment: Are these different objects inside a list? And also provide which language you are using

Comment: @inian yes, but I was not able to extract what I need. I used 'cat info.json | jq '.tech.slug', but I don't know what to to next.

Comment: @Pablo Your JSON is invalid in its current form? Are these objects part of a JSON array?

Comment: @AashishPeepra I mentioned the language in tag part (bash), they are different results inside a json file.

Comment: `"inx": { "sssdg" }` is not a valid JSON key-value pair

Comment: I have a .json file. It contains the output of a command which extracts "tech" section for each "inx" and writes the result inside this .json file.

Comment: Please also note that trailing commas are not allowed in JSON. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#trailing_commas_in_json

Comment: @inian I corrected the json

Comment: `jq` can handle the stream of objects, but not the trailing commas in the array values.

Answer (score 0):

With the JSON- (and HTML/XML) parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) you can do:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json[(tech)()/slug="microsoft-l"]/(inx)()'
tthd
```

or with XQuery 3.1 syntax / functions:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json[tech?*?slug="microsoft-l"]/map:keys(inx)'
tthd
```